# Ceating UITableViewCell on each time cellForRowAtIndexPath calls

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview, ios4

I have created a custom UITableView cell and it has 4-5 various components. Some times I create UIViews from CGRectMake and some times based on some x, y coordinate calculations I position some UIImages. Everthing works fine cos cellForRowAtIndexPath every time creates a new cell. But when Im going to reuse the cell based on "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" the UI gets messed up. The previous rect makes were never get erased and positioning of the earlier UIViews are also behaving weird. Although the cell indexes are changes it does not reflect the coordination of the drawn UIImages.

Creating the UITableViewCell in each cellForRowAtIndexPath works fine in 3GS and 4G but its really annoying and its very slow in 3G. I suspect this behavior is because of creation of this cellForRowAtIndexPath in every call. So can any one help me to identify this problem.

This is what I do now.

```
CustomNoteCell *cell = nil;

if (cell == nil) { 

    cell = (CustomNoteCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomNoteCell" owner:nil options:nil];


for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) { 

    if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) { 

             cell = (CustomNoteCell *) currentObject;  
             break; 
     } 
} 
}

//rest of the codes go here like 
CGSize maximumLablelSize = CGSizeMake(296, 1000); 
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [alue sizeWithFont:cell.customCellNoteText.font constrainedToSize:maximumLablelSize lineBreakMode:cell.customCellNoteText.lineBreakMode]; 
CGRect newFrame = cell.customCellNoteText.frame; 
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height; 
cell.customCellNoteText.frame = newFrame; 
cell.customCellNoteText.text = noteValue; 
cell.uiViewContrlloer = self; 
CGRect addressRect = cell.address.frame; 
addressRect.origin.y = newFrame.origin.y + newFrame.size.height + 10; 
cell.address.frame = addressRect;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you place your dequeue cell call at the wrong place. You should put it before `if (cell == nil)`.

Comment: Yes. I have posted the working example. In this case it works fine. but have slowness in the 3G but works perfectly in 3GS and 4G. But when I dequeue the cell before the if (cell == nil) I get the issues whcih I discussed. So this is my question. I want to dequeue above that line and it should work as expected but at the moment its not.

Comment: Could you do post your actual code that won't work, and with formatting? My eyes hurt now...

Comment: Sorry about that. Formatted it.

Answer (score 0):

As tia mentioned, your cell is always going to be nil. You should try to dequeue earlier.

```
CustomNoteCell *cell = (CustomNoteCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 

if (! cell) {
    cell = [[[CustomNoteCell alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

...

Comment: Thanks Joshpaul. When Im going to reuse the cell based on "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" the UI gets messed up. Thats the issue.

Comment: What is "messed up?" What happens with this approach?

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomNoteCell";
CustomNoteCell *cell = (CustomNoteCell *)[aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (! cell)
{
  cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomNoteCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
}

// customize the cell...

Comment: The issue here is positioning goes wrong. It draws content randomly in every cell.

Comment: How are you setting the height on the cell? Can you push some of this layout logic into the CustomNoteCell class you've created? i.e. [cell setNoteText: noteValue]; ?